# Indefinite articles and chemical elements ("an Mg salt"?)

Tags: indefinite-articles

I am working on chemistry papers and I came across the term "a Mg salt".

I am unsure if chemical elements are read out as their constituent letters (for example, "em gee" for Mg) or if you read them out as the element they represent (magnesium).

Should this term be "*an* Mg salt" or not?
What about compounds with formulas, such as oxides? (e.g., "a Na2O container", "a sodium oxide container")

Thank you.

Clarification: I am interested in knowing if I should use "a" or "an" in written documents. I do not care much about how these terms should be read out in conferences, but feel free to leave comments about that too.

I am editing papers, so the question would be along the lines of if "an Mg salt" would be incorrect usage of the indefinite article in a written document.

Comment: I read element symbols as though the name of the element was written out, and use the proper article on that basis. Thus, "a Mg salt" or "a Na oxide" are correct, because they're "a magnesium salt" or "a sodium oxide". It's also "a U fluoride", because the pronunciation of "uranium" starts with a consonantal "y" sound.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will edit the question a little bit in the part about oxides, but I assume your answer would be the same (i.e., read the oxide as though its full name were written out instead of its formula).

Comment: Yes; the only time I would read the symbol as a symbol ('emm gee') is when I'm specifically talking about the _symbol_ rather than the underlying element, or when I'm reading a formula - "Ethanol is see two aitch five oh aitch".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin that sounds correct and reasonable, but in this video the speaker refers to NaCl initially as "sodium chloride", then subsequently "enn-ay-see-ell".  So perhaps you can do it either way.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIIjMe2kzk4  UPDATE - just saw your second comment where you cover this :)

Comment: You would usually say the whole word ("magnesium salt").  But it's totally commonplace to say (for example) "h 2 o" rather than "water".  Saying "m g salt" would be totally normal and OK.

Comment: As a Licentiate of the Royal Society of Chemistry, I would never write 'a/n Mg salt'. I would regard it as unprofessional and it was never done so in the papers I used to read back in the day. It is a magnesium salt. The chemical symbol is about the chemistry of the salt, MgCl2 or whatever. 'Magnesium salt' is about English wording.

Comment: Pablo, it's unclear if you're asking "How do I read them out?" (ie, when spoken) - or something else ?

Comment: @Fattie I am editing papers, so the question would be along the lines of if "an Mg salt" would be incorrect usage of the indefinite article in a written document.

Comment: @NigelJ's provided the proper solution to this problem (no pun intended). However, for the general issue of how you treat abbreviations and the like, the general principle is that you *write* it with *an* if you (intend to) pronounce it with an initial vowel, and *a* otherwise. So, for example, *NASA* is often pronounced as a word, not as individual letters, so it would be "a NASA spaceship". If you pronounced it as *enn ay ess ay*, it would be "an NASA spaceship" because "enn" starts with a vowel sound. That's why people are referencing pronunciation on your question about writing.

Comment: I think I missed the point of this question.  I thought it was "should we **say** *em-gee* or *magnesium*, but it's just about "a" vs "an", right?  With "a" vs "an", one usually feels more correct.  "an Mg salt" feels more natural than "a Mg salt", to me at least.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, it's about "a" vs "an" in written documents. I guess a reader would feel "an" is more natural if he mentally reads "Mg" as "em gee" instead of "magnesium". But that would depend on individual each reader, I think. I thought there was some official consensus! Maybe I should ask this in a chemistry-related stackexchange page?

Comment: My intuition says that whether you choose "a" or "an," you will sound wrong to many readers; and it would often be possible to write 1 Mg, avoiding the problem; and this would be clearer and more conventional to boot.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That does not make my question off-topic in any way. Additionally, you will find thousands of published papers using abbreviations based on the element symbols. Whether their use is correct or incorrect seems to be open to debate, as none of my reviewers ever objected to their use. However, this was the first time I came across terms such as "a Mg salt" or "a HCl solution".

Comment: Yes; the conventions have changed since my days. I've given an answer and adjusted my voting.

Comment: @MaxWilliams with respect to NaCl, that's a molecular formula rather than an element symbol, so could easily be read differently.

Comment: I am sure @NigelJ has given the very definitive answer here!

Comment: The general rule for acronyms and abbreviations is that you should assume "normal" pronunciation for **your** audience.  If they're most likely to read it as "em gee salt" then you'd use "an".  If "magnesium salt" then you'd use "a".  You have to make the call as to how it will be pronounced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following advice, found in an article by [Michaela Panter, PhD](https://www.aje.com/en/arc/editing-tip-indefinite-article-use-elements/), gives the advice found in the ACS style guide, but other science-related style guides often echo this:

> Should the pronunciation of an element’s full name or its symbol be
>   used to choose an indefinite article?
>
> The American Chemical Society (ACS) style guide states that the full
>   element name, rather than its abbreviated form, should be considered
>   when choosing whether to use *a* or *an*. Therefore,  “a Ag
>   nanoparticle” is correct because this phrase is read as “a silver
>   nanoparticle,” where “silver” begins with a consonant sound;
>   pronouncing the phrase as “ay-gee nanoparticle,” which would merit the
>   use of *an* due to the vowel sound “ay,” is less standard. Here are two
>   additional examples:
>
> A Li battery (“Li” is pronounced “lithium,” which begins with a
>   consonant sound)
>
> An Ar laser (“Ar” is pronounced “argon,” which begins with a vowel
>   sound)

There obviously seems to have been a move away from the insistence on the word rather than the symbol in running text in scientific articles in recent years.

Comment: Edwin, it sounds like actually OP is asking about written comms.  I too thought OP meant spoken form.

Comment: Your last example would often be "an Ar+ laser", pronounced "an argon ion laser". Scientists are no more logical than the rest of humanity.

Answer (score 0):

My first degree was chemistry and I taught biochemistry for many years. I could not have imagined anyone writing “an Mg” as I have never heard anyone say anything other than “magnesium”. To my amazement a [Google ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+Mg%2C+an+Mg&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20Mg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20Mg%3B%2Cc0) showed some people actually do write this. However they are in the minority.

As regards “a/an Na<sub>2</sub>O container”, my advice is don’t either say it or write it if you can spell it out in words. It is clumsy and ugly. This is consistent with the comment @Nigel_J made about writing “magnesium salt” rather than “Mg salt”.

In summary, you seem to be focusing on technical minutiae rather than clear communication. I suggest that you change lenses.

Comment: David (and @Nigel J), this was my initial reaction to this question too (and I actually contributed to a paper once, long ago). However, researching (as all good scientists must do) (I always wanted to be one), I've found that academic scientific style guides mainly accept strings like 'a Mg salt'. Things change.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Yes, if you are writing for a journal you have to play by their rules, and often they are driven by space considerations or the chemicals are so complex they have to use the formula. In my nick of the woods the subjects of pedantry were different: RNAase or RNase for ribonuclease, apostrophes in plurals of capitalized acronyms (RNAs or RNA's). Yawn.